# Analysis Service Hierarchy Aggregation

Tags: ssas, hierarchy, bids

I've read through some documents on how to produce a hierarchy and use it for aggregration.
I have a dimension which I created to produce a hiearchy. Simple one. Two columns. And the drill down works. I did it in Visual Studio.

```
STAT | Management

STAT | Stat Adjustment
```

So that's all good, except Management and Stat Adjustment doesn't add up to a total "STAT".
How do I add the rules so that Management and Stat Adjustment adds to STAT?

I can't find the settings in Visual Studio. And no amount of reading told me how to do it either, just explained natural and unnatural hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Measures define how your data will "add up", not Hierarchies. I would set the Measure property for AggregateFunction to Sum.

Note this can be overriden by the MDX calculation script.

Also I would not use the Visual Studio cube browser for testing - this is based on the OWC control that came out in 2003 and has numerous issues and bugs.  The functionality is also extremely weak e.g. cant save a query or export the results. I would run all tests using the end-user query tool e.g. Excel.

Comment: Thanks for that. Where exactly do I set that aggregate function?

Comment: Ok, I think it wasn't set to Sum because it doesn't make sense to sum across a lot of the dimensions. Is there a way to just sum in certain cuts? ie what I described above, without having to change the aggregation option?

Comment: On each Attribute in a Dimension, you can set IsAggregatable to False.